# Why does Enumerable#find/#detect return an Array even when called on an Hash?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, enumerable

The [documentation for `Enumerable#find`/`#detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) says:

> #### `find(ifnone = nil) { |obj| block } → obj or nil`
>  `find(ifnone = nil) → an_enumerator`
>
> Passes each entry in *enum* to *block*. **Returns the first** for which block
>   is not false. If no object matches, calls *ifnone* and returns its
>   result when it is specified, or returns `nil` otherwise.

However, when it is called on the Hash, the result has changed the type to Array instead of the original Hash.

Is it some implementation fault or some historical conventions regarding this datatype?

```
{a: 'a', b:'b'}.find {|k, v| v == 'b'}
# => [:b, 'b']
```

Comment: What other format would you expect? If it returns the original hash, then there is no point of using it.

Comment: Yes, that's why I am asking a question here. :)

Comment: I agree this is confusing and the docs are basically inaccurate when applied to hashes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Hash#detect` is inherited from `Enumerable#detect` method.

`Enumerable` module generates multiple methods(such as `sort`, `min`, `max` including `detect` etc.) based on the `each` method of the class which includes `Enumerable`.

It doesn't care about how `each` is implemented as long as it

> "...yields successive members of the collection. "
>   from [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html)

So for the `Hash#detect` method, it relies on `Hash#each`'s behavior, which is:

> Calls block once for each key in hsh, passing the key-value pair as
>   parameters. If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

```
h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
h.each {|key, value| puts "#{key} is #{value}" }
```

Because `Hash#each` yields the hash as two pair array, all methods inherited from the `Enumerable` module works based on that.

That's why `Hash#detect` produces a two elements array instead of the an hash object itself.

Answer (score 4):

`find` is implemented in terms of `each`. And `each`, when called on a Hash, returns key-value pairs in form of arrays with 2 elements each. That's why `find` returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

***Using detect/find with Hashes***

With hashes, detect/find passes each key/value pair in the hash to the block, which you can “catch” as either:

*A two-element array, with the key as element 0 and its corresponding value as element 1,* or

```
h = {:a => 'a', :b => 'b'}
p h.find {|k| p k ; k[1] == 'b'}
```

*output:*

```
[:a, "a"]
[:b, "b"]
[:b, "b"]
```

*Two separate items, with the key as the first item and its corresponding value as the second item.*

```
h = {:a => 'a', :b => 'b'}
p h.find {|k, v| puts k,v ; v == 'b'}
```

*Output:*

```
a
a
b
b
[:b, "b"]
```

To get more on this topic look here [`Enumerating Ruby’s “Enumerable” Module, Part 3: “detect”, a.k.a. “find”Enumerating Ruby’s “Enumerable” Module, Part 3: “detect”, a.k.a. “find”`](http://www.globalnerdy.com/2008/02/06/enumerating-ruby%E2%80%99s-enumerable-module-part-3-detect-aka-find/)

Answer (score 0):

I could use this:

```rb
h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }.keys.include?("a") # for key

h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }.values.include?(100) # for value
```