# Convert Array of Hashes to a Hash

Tags: ruby, hash, nested

I'm trying to convert the following:

```
dep = [
      {id: 1, depen: 2},
      {id: 1, depen: 3},
      {id: 3, depen: 4},
      {id: 5, depen: 3},
      {id: 3, depen: 6}
]
```

Into a single hash:

```
# {1=>2, 1=>3, 3=>4, 5=3, 3=>6}
```

I tried a solution I found on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035567/add-key-value-pair-to-array-of-hashes-when-unique-ids-match):

```
dep.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g[:id]] = g[:dep_id] }
```

However, the output removed elements and gave me:

```
#{1=>3, 3=>6, 5=>2}
```

where the last element is also incorrect.

Comment: `dep.map(&:values).to_h #=> {1=>3, 3=>6, 5=>3}`. You cannot, of course have duplicate keys. `1=>3` updates the value of `1` from `2` to `3`; `3=>6` updates the value of `3` from `4` to `6`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **cannot** have a hash like `{1=>2, 1=>3, 3=>4, 5=3, 3=>6}`. All keys of a hash mst have be unique.

If you want to get a hash mapping each id to a *list* of dependencies, you can use:

```
result = dep.
  group_by { |obj| obj[:id] }.
  transform_values { |objs| objs.map { |obj| obj[:depen] } }
```

Or

```
result = dep.reduce({}) do |memo, val|
  memo[val[:id]] ||= []
  memo[val[:id]].push val[:depen]
  memo
end
```

which produce

```
{1=>[2, 3], 3=>[4, 6], 5=>[3]}
```